# java version still showing as 1.4 linux

Tags: java, linux, version, classpath

java -version still returns old java version. I have red hat linux

I installed jdk 1.5 int eh follwing path and updated the bask profile and did a source but still the java version shows 1.4

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin/java
PATH has /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin

but i still see java -version even from the bin directory /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin as follows

## java -version

java version "1.4.2"
gcj (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10.0.1)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is generally not used by the JDK - it is just a convention sometimes used by other applications. It will not be used by the `java` executable or the operating system to supercede the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the alternatives system to update the symlinks to the correct version of Java - see http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-5593.

Install with:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jre1.6???/bin/java 2
```

Configure with:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

Comment: $  /usr/sbin/alternatives --display java
java - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java - priority 1420
 slave jre: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj
 slave jre_exports: /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.4.2-gcj
 slave rmiregistry: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/rmiregistry
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java.

Comment: this command is nto working /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jre1.6???/bin/java 2

Comment: sorry, the ???? marks are for you to fill in based on your path to the version of the JRE you are installing - it might not even be in opt - on Fedora mine is located at /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/java etc.

Answer (score 4):

> but i still see java -version even from the bin directory /usr/local/jdk/jdk1.5.0_10/bin as follows

Magic: run ./java -version

Note the dot and slash - this tells to execute from current dir.
Unlike DOS, on linux current dir is not in the executable search path by default

And yes, fix your $PATH

Comment: $ ./java -version
java version "1.5.0_06"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_06-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_06-b05, mixed mode)

Comment: what needs to be fixed in $PATH? Shall I move the java path in the beginning of the path?

Comment: yep, move it to the beginning

Answer (score 4):

Generally each distro has their own mechanism for choosing the version of Java to use.  Also  this mechanism generally allows Java to be setup differently for each user.

[Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) - sudo update-alternatives --config java

[Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/Java)

[Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/java.xml) - Uses java-config

[Fedora Core](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-Java-in-Fedora-Core-6-39724.shtml)  uses alternatives --config java

Answer (score 3):

Oh, yes.

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

Displays:

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
```

Then you can choose your version.  In my case, Java-7 (option 2)

Answer (score 2):

Try issuing the command "which java" to discover exactly what version of the java command is being executed.  If you just appended the new path to the end of your PATH, then the shell will still use the old one because it'll find that one first.