# Java migration 1.4 version to higher versions

Tags: java, linux

How to upgrade the java version from 1.4 to next version in linux ?
When i give a command java -version , getting output having java 1.4 version.
 I want to upgrade from java 1.4  to java 1.6 version. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Don't get 1.6. Go directly to Java 8 (or at least 7). How? Download the latest version from Oracle (or OpenJDK).

Comment: I personally had issues with OpenJDK and had to ignore my package manager and go with Oracle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165061/java-version-still-showing-as-1-4-linux?rq=1 is also worth reading - it might be the case that newer versions are already installed on your system but the default still is the very old 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could download Java off the net, extract it and install it, you should stick to using your distribution's package manager in order to ensure proper version management and maintainability of your OS. Each Linux distribution has its own package manager (Debian uses `apt`/`dpkg`, Red Hat uses `yum` and so forth), so you should familiarize yourself with the relevant package manager and take it from there.

(Also, positively consider @Thilo's advice about skipping 1.6.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `which java` should be able to tell you where java is installed on your local Linux server. It is likely to be a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/java` (I say usually because on AIX it is different).

Now, assuming you have a new version of JAVA installed in `/usr/local/java_xxxx` (you decide which one you want), simply update your symbolic link to `java` and `javac`.

```
ln -s -v /usr/local/java_xxxx/java /usr/bin/java
ln -s -v /usr/local/java_xxxx/javac /usr/bin/javac
```

And now `java -version` should give you the latest installed copy. For other 'detailed' instructions look [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Java-on-Linux)

Comment: I am able to get the java -version with the new version after upgrading but the below output is getting having the earlier version of java componets. 
$/usr/sbin/alternatives --display java (Here best option is slecting the older version of java instead new version)
 How to avoid here without getting older version of java things and only having newer versions without having null values for slaves