# Set Java version on Linux Shell

Tags: java, linux

I am running the following script on Linux Centos 7.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo | java -version
echo "maven build ..."
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

With this output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2
java version "1.7.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.12.0.el7_4-x86_64 u161-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.161-b00, mixed mode)
maven build ...
```

As you can see, the java version is `1.7.0_161`.

**Question**

How do I set the java version to java 14, so that maven builds with java 14?

**More info:**

The java 14 version I installed and I set the `JAVA_HOME` on is from here: https://jdk.java.net/14/ (Linux / x64)

p.s. I only want to use java 14 for this maven build. I still want to keep Java 1.7 globally.

**UPDATE**

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jsk.version>2.2.3</jsk.version>
    <start-class>com.nexct.approvalservice.NexctApprovalServiceApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Add -V to maven command line to see which version of Java is used.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the reply. After adding -V, I get:  `Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 1.7.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.161-2.6.12.0.el7_4.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165061/java-version-still-showing-as-1-4-linux) out?

Comment: @AmitKumar, thanks. I am trying to figure `update-alternatives` out.

Comment: I find this a bit confusing. Your title and tags mention Linux and shell, but you really seem to be concerned about a Maven build? Can't you just [specify the Java version in the build script](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)?

Comment: Hi Robert, that's the thing, I do specify the java version in my POM file, but it doesn't seem to work. So on my dev environment I set the JAVA_HOME, and that works. Am I doing something wrong when trying to set java 14 in the pom? (see update above in the original question).

Comment: I have asked a specific question with your suggested updates here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048137/setting-java-version-for-maven-build?noredirect=1#comment111491889_63048137

Answer (score 0):

Search for the location where maven is installed.

In windows when you unzip the apache-maven.zip it contains a bin directory.

Path looks like this in my system. **E:\builds\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn**

You need to check what is the value for JAVA_HOME is set in mvn file.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: That sounds terribly complicated; why would I modify installed packages to specify the Java version to be used for compiling *my* code? The next system upgrade will also overwrite your change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set more than `JAVA_HOME`.  Do something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This changes the JAVA_HOME to your Java 14 install but then also changes where the shell finds things like `javac` and so on.

I create a script like the above named, in this case `java14`, and then can (assuming bash shell) do a `source /home/me/bin/java14` (I store it in my local `bin` directory) to change it when I need.

I find this easier than `update-alternatives`.  I often want to make a change for a single window, not the entire machine.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I like your approach, because as you say it is simpler the `update-alternatives`.  However, when I try it in my `.sh` file, it doesn't change the java version. Am I doing something wrong? I do: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`, but get: `Java version: 1.7.0_161`.

Comment: Setting the `JAVA_HOME` works for me on a MacOS, but on Linux Centos7 I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: You need to `source` the file, not run it.  When you do the `source` command it's the same as typing it.  If you run it as a shell it's set during the running of that shell and then it's not.  So create your file and then run `source /path/to/my/file.sh` on both MacOS and CentOS and it should work.