# Can Maven reference JAVA_HOME from inside the POM file

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to set a property in a POM file with reference to `$JAVA_HOME`?

```
<executable><$JAVA_HOME>/bin/javac</executable>
```

The reason I am doing this is the only way I can get maven to use the correct compiler version is by setting the `<executable>`. But I don't want to hard-code the `JAVA_HOME` location in the pom file.

Comment: Can we have more context on why you want to do this? In general maven should already know about and respect `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: You can refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503658/specify-jdk-for-maven-to-use

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a different jdk than the one that maven uses.

Comment: My question stems from this question where I cannot get maven to use the version of java I want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048137/setting-java-version-for-maven-build/63048917?noredirect=1#comment111493403_63048917

Comment: @Richard in that question you seem to have completely other problem. I think either your "mvn" script or settings.xml is somehow broken, as it should use JAVA_HOME by default, but doesn't seem to.

Comment: @eis yes, there is some very strange behaviour on the server. I am still trying to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: If you really need to use a different JDK for running Maven and the JDK you would like to build with (compile/test) you should take a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `${env.ANY_ENV_VARIABLE}` to get env variables in pom.xml.
So just use `${env.JAVA_HOME}` in your case

Comment: ...but note that maven already should use JAVA_HOME, so it is expected that this will change nothing - unless something else has been manually changed in the maven settings or script